# Using InjectorFactory for routerProviders or routerProvidersHash can be automated?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I'm bootstrap angular with runApp and the namend Parameter "createInjector" to define the routerStrategy "routerProviders" or "routerProvidersHash".
Is there any way to automate this definition like i wish to do this in my first line? For local development i wish to use "routerProvidersHash" and for live environment is wanna use the "routerProvider".

```dart
const List<Provider<Object>> routerStrategy = Environment.isLive() ? routerProviders : routerProvidersHash;
@GenerateInjector([
  routerStrategy,
  ClassProvider(Client, useClass: BrowserClient),
])
final InjectorFactory injector = self.injector$Injector;

void main() {
  runApp(ng.AppComponentNgFactory, createInjector: injector);
}
```

The problem is, that this value need to be a const, but then i can not create the constant like this.
I have no idea to make this more flexible :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is const very much on purpose as if it is dynamic like you suggest then it can't be optimized.

What I think you can do is have two injectors one for devel, and one for prod and decide which one to use when you call runApp.

Comment: I did it your way and it works fine! :)

Nevertheless, its bad boilerplate for toggle this behaviour.

Comment: Since this framework is made for scale we do sometimes trade boilerplate for performance. Having the injectors not be run time dynamic allows us to make things much more performant. Hope you understand.

Comment: I already thought so :) ... nevertheless: good work, i like dart and angularDart - thx for that :)