# AngularDart: How to configure routerProviders / routerProvidersHash for development and production environments?

Tags: angular-dart

There is one [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56741536/using-injectorfactory-for-routerproviders-or-routerprovidershash-can-be-automate) about same problem. But I can't find production-ready code example how to use `routerProviders` / `routerProvidersHash` in real application.

As I understand we need to define two injectors and use one of them depending on compile time environment variable, like shown below.

```dart
// File: web/main.dart

// >>> Have to use 2 injectors:
@GenerateInjector([
  routerProvidersHash,
  ClassProvider(Client, useClass: BrowserClient),
])
final InjectorFactory injectorDev = self.injectorDev$Injector;

@GenerateInjector([
  routerProviders,
  ClassProvider(Client, useClass: BrowserClient),
])
final InjectorFactory injectorProd = self.injectorProd$Injector;
// <<<

void main() {
  final env = ServerEnvironment();
  if (env.isProduction) {
    runApp(ng.AppComponentNgFactory, createInjector: injectorProd);
  } else {
    runApp(ng.AppComponentNgFactory, createInjector: injectorDev);
  }
}
```

```dart
// File: lib/server_environment.dart

enum ServerEnvironmentId { development, production }

class ServerEnvironment {

  ServerEnvironmentId id;

  static final ServerEnvironment _instance = ServerEnvironment._internal();
  factory ServerEnvironment() => _instance;

  ServerEnvironment._internal() {
    const compileTimeEnvironment = String.fromEnvironment('MC_ENVIRONMENT', defaultValue: 'development');
    if (compileTimeEnvironment != 'development') {
      id = ServerEnvironmentId.production;
    } else {
      id = ServerEnvironmentId.development;
    }
  }

  bool get isProduction {
    return id == ServerEnvironmentId.production;
  }

}
```

```
File: build.production.yaml

targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      build_web_compilers|entrypoint:
        generate_for:
          - web/main.dart
        options:
          compiler: dart2js
          # List any dart2js specific args here, or omit it.
          dart2js_args:
          - -DMC_ENVIRONMENT=production
          - --fast-startup
          - --minify
          - --trust-primitives
```

```sh
# Build execution

pub run build_runner build --config production --release -o web:build
```

Is the assumption of having two injectors is the right way to do?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is make a different main.dart file for your different injector setup.  You shouldn't have too much stuff in main.dart it should just serve as a mechanism to start your app.  The branching should occur in build.production.yaml as specifying a different main for production (i.e. web/main_production.dart) and this file is the one with the non-hash route provider.  This would remove the need for a "ServerEnvironment" and a if/else with a potentially confusing double injector setup in one file.

```
// File: web/main.dart

@GenerateInjector([
  routerProvidersHash,
  ClassProvider(Client, useClass: BrowserClient),
])
final InjectorFactory injector = self.injector$Injector;

void main() {
  runApp(ng.AppComponentNgFactory, createInjector: injector);
}
```

and

```
// File: web/main_production.dart

@GenerateInjector([
  routerProviders,
  ClassProvider(Client, useClass: BrowserClient),
])
final InjectorFactory injector = self.injector$Injector;

void main() {
  runApp(ng.AppComponentNgFactory, createInjector: injector);
}
```

with

```
File: build.production.yaml

targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      build_web_compilers|entrypoint:
        generate_for:
          - web/main_production.dart
        options:
          compiler: dart2js
          # List any dart2js specific args here, or omit it.
          dart2js_args:
          - --fast-startup
          - --minify
          - --trust-primitives
```

Ran as

```
# Build execution

pub run build_runner build --config production --release -o web:build
```

Comment: Thank you Brian! When using `main_production.dart` the name of generated JS-file will be `main_production.dart.js`. But in file `index.html` it is set to `<script defer src="main.dart.js"></script>`. How to handle this case when PROD and DEV environment need to use different JS-files?

Comment: I filed an issue https://github.com/dart-lang/build/issues/2628 based on the fact that it seems to override if you used the `--out=web/main.dart.js` in the `dart2js_args` which you should be able to do since it is supported in `dart2js` ..